# Python tests in all directories?

Tags: python

my structure is like this:

```
main_folder
   |
   -- proj1
     |------ code
          |-------- __init__.py
          |-------- my_file_proj1.py
     |-------test
          |-------- __init__.py
          |-------- test_my_file_proj1.py
   -- proj2
     |------ code
          |-------- __init__.py
          |-------- my_file_proj2.py
     |-------test
          |-------- __init__.py
          |-------- test_my_file_proj2.py
```

I want to run *all* tests under `main_folder` so that means tests under all subdirectories. The problem is when I run:

`python -m unittest discover .` It gives:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 0 tests in 0.000s
```

However when I run:

`python -m unittest discover proj1` or `python -m unittest discover proj2`

It detects all tests and runs properly.

How can I make it recursively run all tests in all subdirectories from `main_folder`?

Comment: The first sentence [in the docs says](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#test-discovery): "In order to be compatible with test discovery, all of the test files must be modules or packages". Your main folder does not meet this requirement.

Comment: @Mark I see, is there a way to fix this?